# Relatives : « que ... en faire » ou « dont ... faire »

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-relatifs, subordonnées

> Je suis désolé que ce produit ne convienne pas à l'usage que vous voulez en faire.

Je suis tombé sur cette phrase, et la question qui m'est venue à l'esprit est: pourquoi ne dit-on pas plutôt « Je suis désolé que ce produit ne convienne pas à l'usage dont vous voulez faire. » ?

C'est vrai que la phrase que je propose a l'air incorrecte mais pourquoi elle est fausse grammaticalement parlant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si on extrait le contenu de la relative ça donne ça :

> Vous voulez faire usage de ce produit.

Si on veut caractériser l' « usage », qui est utilisé comme un object *direct* de *faire* dans la construction verbale (bien qu'il n'y ait pas d'article) on utilise le pronom relatif *que* :

> L'usage que vous voulez faire de ce produit.
>
> L'usage que vous voulez en faire.

Si on souhaite caractériser le « produit », qui est objet indirect de la construction verbale *faire usage*, on utilise *dont* ainsi :

> Le produit dont vous voulez faire usage.

Dans la phrase donnée en exemple, c'est l' « usage » qui est utile dans le reste de la phrase. D'où le premier choix.

Answer (score 1):

Seul « que » est utilisable ici.

> Je suis désolé que ce produit ne convienne pas à l'usage **que** vous voulez en faire.

Avec « dont », la phrase aurait pu être:

> Je suis désolé que ce produit ne convienne pas à l'usage **dont** nous avions parlé.

Comment: @jllagre: "dont nous avions parlé" ou "dont nous avons parlé": je pense que les deux passent?

Comment: Pourquoi ma phrase est fausse?

Comment: @Frank Oui, les deux, suivant le contexte.

Comment: @jillagre - je n'arrive pas à voir une grosse différence dans le cas présent. Je vois bien que c'est deux expressions différentes, je peux me forcer à trouver une différence de sens, mais dans la pratique, j'utiliserais sans doute "dont nous avons parlé" sans trop réfléchir.

Comment: @Frank Si la découverte de l'inadéquation est antérieure à l'instant présent, le plus-que-parfait est plus précis. Il permet de mieux situer dans le temps la discussion par rapport à cette constatation.

Comment: @jlliagre - ah oui c'est vrai. Maintenant que j'y pense, en soumettant les deux expressions à la fameuse épreuve du « gueuloir » (haha), je sens la différence, effectivement.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives:

> Je suis désolé que ce produit ne soit pas conforme à l'usage dont nous avons parlé.
>
> Je suis désolé que ce produit ne soit pas conforme à l'usage que vous voulez en faire.
>
> Je suis désolé que ce produit ne corresponde pas à l'usage dont nous avons parlé.
>
> Je suis désolé que ce produit ne corresponde pas à l'usage que vous voulez en faire.
>
> Je suis désolé que ce produit ne corresponde pas à la facon dont vous voulez l'utiliser.